# Powershell not able to read space in file name

Tags: powershell, tfs, whitespace, sqlplus

I am trying to run sqlplus through powershellscript in TFS.I have a deployment.xml file which has the order in which the sql scripts are to be deployed. my PS script reads the deployment.xml file and then executes the sqlplus command. the deployment.xml has 3 files

1. New SQL FILE.sql
2. sample.sql
3. dfg_ehl.sql

The first file having space in the name is not getting read and is throwing

> error: Cannot open the file because file doesn't exists.

I have tried renaming,replacing and copying the file but the PS script still fails with the

> error"Cannot find path C:...\NEW SQL FILE.sql because it does not exists".

I have also used double quotes but doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
param($username,$password,$schema,$sqlpath)
$xml=[xml] Get-Content deployment.xml
$Query=$xml.deployment.script
Set-Location $sqlpath
foreach($q in $Query)
 {
  sqlplus $username/$password@$schema "@$q"
 }

Deployment.xml
<deployment>
<script>NEW SQL File.sql</script>
<script>sample.sql</script>
</deployment>
```

Please help.
This script doesnt work and throws

> "Cannot find path "C:..\NEW SQL File.sql" as it does not exists.

Answer (score -2):

Surround you filename with double quotes. like "NEW SQL File.sql"
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/08/07/powertip-run-a-powershell-script-with-space-in-the-path/

Comment: replace space with `  see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-run-a-powershell-script-with-space-in-the-path/